# Am I asking for issues with this returned cursor?

Tags: java, android, cursor

Basically I have a method that populates a listview from my database.

I am receiving both null pointers on a cursor and 'unable to stop activity' errors.

This is how I am returning my cursor:

```
public Cursor getAppointmentsData() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWAPPID, KEY_NAMEAPP,
            KEY_TYPEAPP, KEY_TIMEAPP, KEY_DATEAPP, KEY_COMMENTAPP };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLEAPP, columns, null, null,
            null, null, KEY_NAMEAPP + " ASC", null);

    if (c != null) {
        if (c.getCount() > 0 && c.moveToFirst())

        {
            c.moveToFirst();

            return c;

        }

    }
    c.close();
    return null;
}
```

When the database is empty i.e there are no data, it will crash...if there is data it is fine. This leaves me to believe I am returning a null value from my cursor.

Can you guys see issues with this method of returning the cursor?

Sorry for the simple question but before I tear the code apart I thought I would ask here.

New edit:

public Cursor getAppointmentsData() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWAPPID, KEY_NAMEAPP,
                KEY_TYPEAPP, KEY_TIMEAPP, KEY_DATEAPP, KEY_COMMENTAPP };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLEAPP, columns, null, null,
                null, null, KEY_NAMEAPP + " ASC", null);

```
    if (c != null) {

            c.moveToFirst();

        }
    c.close();
    return c;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do the following

```
if (c.moveToFirst()){
    return c;
}
```

The reason for this is, that the `query()` method will not return a null. It will just return a empty cursor. So, there is no need to check if its null. Also, `moveToFirst()` evaluates to false if it cannot move to the first row (hence, if the cursor is empty). So, the count check is redundant.

However, are you sure that it is safe to return null from your method? You are explictially returning a null if there is no results. Also, are you aware that the `close()` method is never called after the return (in case you have a cursor with result).

I dont't know entirely what you do with the cursor being returned my your method, but I'd suggest you to simply just return it. But I suspect that what you want is simply

```
public Cursor getAppointmentsData() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWAPPID, KEY_NAMEAPP,
            KEY_TYPEAPP, KEY_TIMEAPP, KEY_DATEAPP, KEY_COMMENTAPP };
    return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLEAPP, columns, null, null,
            null, null, KEY_NAMEAPP + " ASC", null);
}
```

**UPDATE - Regarding when to close the cursor**

If you close the cursor, before you return it, then the method `getAppointmentsData()` will return a closed cursor. I'm pretty sure this is not what you are after. Since at this stage, you are not done with the cursor, so its too early to clean up after yourself :)

What you are after is something like this. First, use the method `getAppointmentsData()` i suggested above, which doesn't close the cursor, it just returns it. Now build your cursor adapter something like this

```
public CursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //... all your stuff
    myCursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(this, getAppointmentsData());
}
```

Now, pass the cursor adaptor to your ListView, and at this stage, the ListView can use the underlying cursor (because its still live, as in, not closed :P). Then, when you are certain your application doesn't need the cursor any more, close it. I'd suggest to do it when your activity is destroyed

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   myCursorAdapter.getCursor().close(); 
}
```

Comment: That is a great explanation. I have to be honest and say i wasnt aware that simply an empty cursor would be returned if the 'if' stataement was not triggered. I knew i was heading for trouble when i had the return type 'null' at the bottom of the method. I will implement this and see how I get on. I am opening and closing the database in my class that calls this cursor method.

Comment: closing my cursor through c.close() is still required correct?

Comment: yes, close it when you are done with it. Not after the return, since nothing after return is evaluated (and also, you obviously aren't done with the instance at this stage anyways. if you where, you wouldn't return it from a method :))

Comment: Again thankls for your answer. I have added my new method to my orginal question. If you could please check it that would be great. I have added my cursor close object before i return the cursor.

Comment: I'll add another section to my answer.